# Append column to newly created dataframe by selecting column from old dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am reading a JSON and I have a dictionary(dictn) whose keys tell me which all columns I should select from JSON df.

I am trying to create a new df and then appending those columns whose keys from dictn were present in JSON  but I am getting the below **error**:
Any help on this one is greatly appreciated as I am really new to spark.

> 'Resolved attribute(s) ip#238 missing from  in operator !Project [ip#238 AS ip#267].;;\n!Project [ip#238 AS ip#267]\n+- LogicalRDD false\

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

jsn={"body":[{"ip":"177.284.10.91","sg_message_id":"YcbG1IBnQ1-626TaUVg2bQ.filter1049p1las1-18982-5C868E5A-20.0","hostname":"d2214390ce89","useragent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.2; E6810) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.105 Mobile Safari/537.36","method_name":"mass_gifting","email":"test@aol.com","timestamp":1554076768,"url":"https://engagement.test.com/b/genghisgrill","object_id":42813,"category":["42813-3-11-19-bottomless-is-back","713","mass_gifting"],"sg_event_id":"Krfn-yDfTG-CQ-o8zhTb0w","event":"click","klass":"3-11-19-bottomless-is-back","url_offset":{"index":3,"type":"html"},"rails_env":"production","user_id":78003906,"business_id":713}],"account":"testaccount"}

dictn={'ip':'string',
       'sg_message_id':'string',
       'hostname':'string',
       'method_name':'string',
       'email':'string',
       'timestamp':'bigint',
       'smtp-id':'string',
       'object_id':'bigint',
       'response':'string',
       'sg_event_id':'string',
       'tls':'string',
       'event':'string',
       'klass':'string',
       'user_id':'string',
       'rails_env':'string',
       'business_id':'bigint'}
schema = StructType([])
new_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
a=[json.dumps(jsn)]
jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(a)
df = spark.read.json(jsonRDD)
x=df.select("body")
df1=df.withColumn("foo",explode("body")).select("foo.*")
for k1,v1 in dictn.items():
  if k1 in df1.columns:
      new_df=new_df.withColumn(k1,df1[k1])
  else:
      new_df=new_df.withColumn(k1,lit(10))
new_df.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you're trying to add new columns by referencing columns from another DataFrame which is actually not supported in Spark. 
The question was already asked and answered here: [Add a column from another DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853778/add-a-column-from-another-dataframe)

But to achieve what you want here you just need to use `select` from `df1` which gives you new DataFrame with a list of columns that you get from the dict.

This should work fine for you:

```
select_expr = [col(c).alias(c) if c in df1.columns else lit(10).alias(c) for c, _ in dictn.items()]

new_df = df1.select(select_expr)

new_df.show()
```

Comment: it gives me :  name 'col' is not defined

Comment: add `from pyspark.sql.functions import col`