# How to merge a column from df1 to df2 pyspark>

Tags: pyspark

I want to merge two dataframes columns into one new dataframe.
df1 has columns x1,x2,x3
df2 has column x4
new_df should be x1,x2,x3,x4
There are no joining conditions just need to merge all the columns together.

I have tried `df1.merge(df2)` but no luck with this.
throws an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'merge'`

this is a pyspark dataframe.

Comment: Answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853778/add-a-column-from-another-dataframe

Comment: @DamiãoMartins It only merges the first columns of both dataframes.

Comment: If there are no overlapping columns, you should specify the order somehow for both tables. That's because Spark does not know which line goes before which - rows are split into multiple nodes. You see the order based on whichever row _happened_ to come first.